decode a message from an echo
I have a signal $s(t)$ which carries a message. To simplify I take a single echo and the signal received is given by: $r(t)=s(t)+\alpha s(t-\tau)$. Additionally, I assume the value of $\tau$ and $\alpha$ known to the receiver.
I would like to know if it is possible to decode the message only from $\alpha s(t-\tau)$. I thought about the Rake receiver but I don't think it works. Afterwards, I thought about the product $r(t)r(t-\tau)$ but I don't see how to continue.

why do you think the Rake receiver won't work? We can't really look inside of your head, and it seems you make assumptions on the nature of your signal or your receiver, which we can't know.

As asked, the question is trivial. If you have the echo $y(t) = alpha s(t-\tau)$ you can always recover the original signal as $s(t) = \frac{1}{\alpha} y(t+\tau)$.  If $\alpha < 1$ you can also recover the $s(t)$ from $r(t)$ as $S(\omega) = \frac{R(\omega)}{1+\alpha e^{-j\omega}}$. Is there anything more to your question?

It seems you mentally skip an important part: You assume you get the echo – and the echo alone. How is that going to happen? It's on the same frequency as your transmission, and absolutely linearly dependent on it; you can't just "separate" $s(t)$ and $\alpha s(t-\tau)$: that would already constitute the equalization.
So: This is an equalizer problem. Many systems work using equalizers, so:

I would like to know if it is possible to decode the message

yes, assuming your system is designed that way.
In the generality you stated your problem – we can't know what it would! We have no information on whether your receiver knows anything about the statistics / spectrum of $s(t)$, nor whether you can include pilot signals etc.
In general, you seem to know about equalizers already – you mention a very classic one – and you seem to know that their application requires some conditions to be met (e.g., you need a pulse shape that has good autocorrelation properties for the rake receiver to make sense). So, you need to make statements about the nature of noise and signal, on the statistical distribution of $\alpha$ and $\tau$ for this to be something you can design for.
